# rebuild drupal form in ajax-submit?

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, form-submit

I'm trying to build an AJAX-submitted form in Drupal 7.7, which should submit its content and empty itself afterwards. Therefore I added an ajax-handler function to the submit button, which calls drupal_get_form() (with the same form-id) and returns the ajax commands to replace the whole form. But for some reason the drupal_get_form-call never returns and instead re-submits the form and redirects afterwards.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Please post your code.  You may also want to try asking at http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: The problem is hard to explain in code, since it happens in conjunction with 3 different functions and only when using ajax. But I didn't now drupal.stackexchange.com exists! I'll try it there. Thanks!